# What does "in abundance" modify in "These dogs have silliness in abundance"?

Tags: adverbial-phrases, parsing

> These dogs have silliness in abundance.

What does "in abundance" modify? Is it "have" or "silliness"

Someone told me that it modifies a noun, but I don't agree.

Is there someone who explains it to me?

Comment: I'd say that the PP "in abundance" is a quantifier modifying the VP "have silliness".

Comment: My parse is this: These dogs/have/silliness/in abundance. In abundance is the same as abundant: so it is adjectival. Silliness in abundance was on display for everyone to see. = Abundant silliness was on display for everyone to see.

Comment: The sentence can be rephrased, "It's in abundance that the dogs have silliness." This suggests it's an adverbial modifying either the VP as BillJ has suggested, or the whole clause, but not just the noun, so it's not adjectival.

Comment: *Silliness in abundance* is a valid noun phrase; it can serve as a subject or object or with a copula, and be modified by an adjective or adjectival phrase.

Answer (score 1):

"Silliness in abundance" means the same as "an abundance of silliness". It acts as a quantifier because it means there is "lots" of something.

This could really have been answered by a dictionary. "In abundance" is defined as an idiom in Websters, for example.

Answer (score 1):

"in abundance" is a [prepositional phrase](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/preposition/prepositional-phrases/).

Prepositional phrases can be used  as adverbs or adjectives:

> He ate cakes in abundance -*adjectival- modifies cakes*
> He vomited in abundance -*adverbial- modifies vomited*

> These dogs have silliness in abundance

In this sentence, **in abundance** can be considered as an adverb modifying have, or as an adjective modifying silliness: semantically, the two interpretations are identical.

To demonstrate the viability of the adverbial form, consider replacing the noun with a lengthy noun phrase: it is necessary to move the prepositional phrase to after the verb, to avoid confusion. [Prepositional phrases are always used postpositively](https://www.grammarflip.com/curriculum/prepositional-phrases-as-adjectives) when used as adjectives, ie after the noun they modify, so **in abundance** cannot be an adjective in the following sentence- it can only be adverbial.

> These dogs have in abundance the kind of hair that blocks a vacuum cleaner

Answer (score 0):

"abundance" is a noun, and therefore is not directly a modifier. It is part of the participial phrase "in abundance", and it is that participial phrase that is a modifier. I would say that it modifies the noun "silliness". This conclusion is supported by the fact that "silliness in abundance" is a quite valid noun phrase. A counterargument would be that the sentence can be phrased as "Silliness is something that these dogs have in abundance". While that phrasing would make it seem like "in abundance" modifies "have", but many sentences can be reworded this way despite the modifier modifying the verb, so I don't find that dispositive.

Comment: how can "in abundance" be a participial phrase when it doesn't contain a participle?